# Click button to copy document to another view

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

I have two views which are *Computer* and *Draft*. I create a button in computer view and it is to create a copy of computer document to draft view.

Below is my button code. When I click the button, it said "Object variable not set"

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim dc As NotesDocumentCollection
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Dim view As NotesView

    Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
    Set view = db.GetView( "Draft" )
    Set doc = dc.GetFirstDocument()
    Set dc = db.AllDocuments
    While Not (doc Is Nothing)
        Call doc.CopyToDatabase(db)
        Set doc = dc.GetNextDocument(doc)
    Wend
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me? And can I ask, do I need to insert any formula inside Draft view? Thanks for any help!

#### Update Question


I have found the problem and fixed my code. But when I click the button, it copies all document and shows on both views. How can I want a copy of the document in Draft only selected document? For example, the "Active" document only? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views do not "contain" documents. Documents are in a database, and views show selected documents, using a SELECT formula. If your SELECT matches all documents, all documents will show up. That formula decides which documents are part of the view.

If view A contains your document and view B doesn't, you have to adapt the SELECT formula in view B so that it will match the document.

E.g. if you want your current document to show up in view B, you could add a value to the current document, like DocumentViews, and set it to "B", and set the SELECT formula of view B to SELECT DocumentViews="B".

Now, if you want to do something with the document that's currently selected in a view, you can use the NotesDatabase.UnprocessedDocuments property. It contains a list of all selected documents.

```
Dim ns As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Set db= ns.CurrentDatabase
Dim dc As NotesDocumentCollection
Set dc= db.UnprocessedDocuments
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Set doc= dc.GetFirstDocument
Dim newdoc As NotesDocument
Do Until doc Is Nothing
    ' you might have to check the status of the current document before copying...
    Set newdoc= doc.CopyToDatabase(db)
    Call newdoc.ReplaceItemValue("Status", "Draft")
    Call newdoc.Save(True, False)
    Set doc= dc.GetNextDocument(doc)
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know about the SELECT formula, but for my case, I want to use copying a document. I want to create a copy of the document and send to Draft view. On Draft view, I can edit the document without affect Computer document. After that, I save copy document as Live document at Computer view, and old computer value I will set it as Inactive and move to Inactive view. So this is my first step. :) Hope you understand. Thanks!

Comment: I'll put some code into the answer, you can use it as a starting point. How do you intend to display one document in the Computer view and the other in the Draft view? And then move the first document to the Inactive view and the 2nd document to the Computer view?? I suppose you need some sort of status field in a document, and move documents when the status changes. Not easy...

Comment: Hey, thanks for your code. I already implement with my code. I still have a problem. How can I differentiate between the original document and copy document? Because when I use the code, it will display copy document too in the same view as it will display two documents. How can I want to show the only original document in Computer view and delete copy document, while on Draft view only show copy document? I don't know how to differentiate between those two documents.

Comment: That's where your SELECT formula comes in. I added the Status field, but you could use any ither fiels to mark the difference between two documents. Do not forget that your new document could become the old document some day, so that there are multiple copies of the original document in the database...

Comment: So the "Status" is my field name or the data inside the field? and "Draft" changes for copy document?

Comment: I successful achieve the view and Thanks. Another question, for your code, I can only pick one document only for every copy. If I want to copy all document in one time, should I use db.Alldocument?

Comment: Nope. You should loop through the Unprocessed documents. Code above will be modified...

Comment: Okay will do. Thanks for your help